# CMake: How do I avoid missmatch in HDF5 system and conda installation?

Tags: c++, cmake, conda, hdf5

I have a CMake project that links to the hdf5 library. On my system I have two version of hdf5: one installed with the system's package manager and one installed with conda. I want to use the conda version to build my project. To do so I use CMake to find the hdf5 library with

```
    find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS CXX)
```

This defines the HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS variable just fine to the conda installation. However the HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES variable gets messed up and includes paths to both library paths. Also the system's installation appears first. So when I check the build variables with ccmake, the HDF_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5 ist set to the conda path and the HDF5_CXX_LIBRARY_hdf5_cpp is set to the system path and therefore I get a undefined reference error when building. Changing the latter variable with ccmake solves the problem. However, this is not a satisfying solution.

Is there a way to make sure that only the path to the conda library is used by CMake?

Comment: Make sure that the discovery path is only using conda (putting it first, to start with).

Comment: Also the issue that you have at link time would appear also at execution time, as the wrong library would be picked up.

Comment: How to do opposite of this?  my cmake is finding the conda include for hdf5 and I want it to use the hfd5/serial which is ubuntu install

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by setting the HDF5_ROOT to CONDA_ROOT. Thus CMake would look first in the conda root dir for HDF5 and identify the right version.